# "Can't set headers after they are sent" - when setting response directly

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, nestjs

I'm using NestJS for my API server and am very satisfied with it.
Most of my controller functions are calling async functions and return JSON - works like a charm.

But in some controller functions, i need to set the response/headers/etc directly to the response object, e.g.:

```js
@Get('api/media')
async getMedia(@Param('id') id: string,
               @Req() req) {
    let result = await getMediaFromBackend(id);
    req.res.set('Content-Type', result.contentType); // need to set content-type dynamically
    req.res.send(result.data); // send non-json response
}
```

In some other case i need to pipe a gzipStream.

It works, but i'm always getting an unhandled rejection in the console:

> "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Seems like NestJS wants to set/overwrite Headers after the controller function returns.
Any ideas how to avoid this? I would need some functionality to tell NestJS like "im taking full care of the response myself"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're injecting `@Req()` and access the response via `req.res` the standard nest controller behavior is used. If you directly use `@Res` instead nest won't mess with the response object and you have full control over it.

```
@Get('api/media')
async getMedia(@Param('id') id: string,
               @Res() res) {
    let result = await getMediaFromBackend(id);
    res.set('Content-Type', result.contentType); // need to set content-type dynamically
    res.send(result.data); // send non-json response
}
```

Caution! This means interceptors, exception filters etc. won't work for this route.

Comment: thanks a lot - that solved my issue.
i remember some post where i read that with req.res you can get the original response object - which also makes total sense now.

Comment: This doesn't work `TypeError: response.set is not a function`

Comment: @Pian0_M4n Is this a runtime or compile error? You might have added a wrong type. See this running example proving it *does* work: https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-typescript-starter-z2zb3?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp.controller.ts